# What is the best way to trim a list?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a List of strings. Its being generated elsewhere but i will generate it below to help describe this simplified example

```
var list = new List<string>();
list.Add("Joe");
list.Add("");
list.Add("Bill");
list.Add("Bill");
list.Add("");
list.Add("Scott");
list.Add("Joe");
list.Add("");
list.Add("");

list = TrimList(list);
```

I would like a function that `"trims"` this list and by trim I want to remove all items at the end of the array that are blank strings (the final two in this case).

**NOTE**: I still want to keep the blank one that is the second item in the array (or any other one that is just not at the end) so I can't do a `.Where(r=> String.isNullOrEmpty(r))`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would just write it without any LINQ, to be honest- after all, you're modifying a collection rather than just querying it:

```
void TrimList(List<string> list)
{
    int lastNonEmpty = list.FindLastIndex(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
    int firstToRemove = lastNonEmpty + 1;
    list.RemoveRange(firstToRemove, list.Count - firstToRemove);
}
```

If you actually want to create a *new* list, then the LINQ-based solutions are okay... although potentially somewhat inefficient (as `Reverse` has to buffer everything).

Comment: @AlexD: Yeah, that was a bug - and there's a neater way of finding the last index. See my edit :)

Comment: Oh you edited it.. I was gonna say (as per my answer) that the concrete `List<T>` has methods to find indexes.. but you've edited it. So +1 anyway! :)

Comment: @AlexD: Not after my edit - it finds the last index where the string is *not* null or empty. I did have it backwards to start with though. And I had a bug in my RemoveRange call. And my condition. Total fail, basically. I think it's okay now though :)

Comment: @AlexD: Absolutely. Do say if you spot anything else though!

Comment: @AlexD: Yup... another off-by-one error. The condition may even not be needed at all... testing.

Answer (score 3):

Take advantage of `Reverse` and `SkipWhile`.

```
list = list.Reverse().SkipWhile(s => String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).Reverse().ToList();
```

Comment: @user2864740 yes, he is assigning to a list. Nice catch!

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>` (not the interface) has a `FindLastIndex` method. Therefore you can wrap that in a method:

```
static IList<string> TrimList(List<string> input) {
    return input.Take(input.FindLastIndex(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)) + 1)
        .ToList();
}
```

This produces a copy, whereas Jon's modifies the list.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of is to code a loop that starts at the end of the list and searches for an element that is not an empty string.  Don't know of any library functions that would help.  Once you know the last good element, you know which ones to remove.

Be careful not to modify the collection while you are iterating over it.  Tends to break the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

I always like to come up with the most generic solution possible. Why restrict yourself with lists and strings? Let's make an algorithm for generic enumerable!

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> TrimEnd<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Predicate<T> predicate)
    {
        if (predicate == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");
        }

        var accumulator = new LinkedList<T>();
        foreach (var item in enumerable)
        {
            if (predicate(item))
            {
                accumulator.AddLast(item);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var accumulated in accumulator)
                {
                    yield return accumulated;
                }

                accumulator.Clear();

                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var list = new[]
{
    "Joe", 
    "", 
    "Bill", 
    "Bill", 
    "", 
    "Scott", 
    "Joe", 
    "", 
    ""
};
foreach (var item in list.TrimEnd(string.IsNullOrEmpty))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```